# Issue with the client-secret value injection in application my file

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager, ecs-taskdefinition

I have a springboot web application deployed on AWS ECS and using Azure AD authentication to it. I have Azure configuration in the application yml and stored client-secret value in AWS secret manager and referring the secret in the task definition. I have also added required permission to get secret value in the policy.

I assume that the client-secret value in the application yml will have real value when the ecs task definition is executed but when I test the application, I get login/error page but when I hard code the client-secret value in the application, deploy to ECS and test the application. The authentication works.

Application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile:
          tenant-id: real-tenant-id
        credential:
          client-id: real-client-id
          client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
```

Task definition:

```
resource “aws_ecs_task_defintion” “ecs_task” {
family = ecs-task
execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_iam_role.arn
task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_iam_role.arn
requires_compatibilities = [“FARGATE”]

container_defintions =jsonencode([{
 name = ecs-container
 image = local.image_uri

 secrets = [{
  name =  “CLIENT_SECRET”
  valueFrom = secret.arn:CLIENT_SECRET::
}]

}])
}


Looking for some information on why the client-secret value is not injected to the placeholder in application yml during task execution.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass value of **CLIENT_SECRET** using **environment** section in **container_definitions** like this

````
    resource “aws_ecs_task_defintion” “ecs_task” {
family = ecs-task
execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_iam_role.arn
task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_iam_role.arn
requires_compatibilities = [“FARGATE”]

container_defintions =jsonencode([{
 name = ecs-container
 image = local.image_uri

 environment = [{
  name =  “CLIENT_SECRET”
  value = secret.arn:CLIENT_SECRET::
}]

}])
}```
````